# How can I calculate part of a result in my statement?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Lets say I have a figure of 45; the first 25 I want to divide by 50% and the rest divided by 75% - how can I do that in one cell? (or with help from cells in hiddin columns etc).

50% of the first 25 = 12,5
75% of the rest (20) = 15

Sum of the above = 27,5.

My end goal is to produce a column that gets me 27,5 (and even better; multiply this number by another number)

I tried various combinations of IF statements.
I have tried to calculate each step in separate columns - but I don't know how to take part of an absolute number to calculate

Not really any code would make sense, as they have not even come close to yield desired outcome.

FALSE (I was supposed to wright something here, but I have no clue how to even begin the formula)

Comment: If you've tried things, post your efforts please.

Comment: `=IF(M4<=25;M4<=25/2`

But this doens't make any sense, I know. 
Problem is, I have no clue what function I can use to do this.

Comment: You only need arithmetical operators (-, + and /) and possibly IF. If you have no knowledge of Excel this is not the place to start. Break it down into bits (25 * 50%) + ((X-25) * 75%).

Comment: I have knowledge of Excel.
But I need to do same calculation for multiple rows.
Can't be true there is no function letting me "calculate 50% of x for all x values up until 25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the value in `A1`, try:

```
=IF(A1<=25,A1*0.5,12.5+((A1-25)*0.75))
```

As per @SJR his comment, you need arithmetical operators.

[image]

*Don't mind the comma as decimal point, if yourself are using semicolon as delimiter and comma as decimal point the formula would be: `=IF(A1<=25;A1*0,5;12,5+((A1-25)*0,75))`*

Comment: But this only calculate A1*0,25 if A1 <= 25, right?
I need it to calculate for all values from 0-25, no matter A1 > 25.

EDIT: My bad, this actually solves my problem! Thank you both; @SJR,

Comment: My bad, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is made with the intention of maximum flexibility

Column A is for your input number
Column B is for your "first section" (the part that will be halved)
Column C is for your "second section" (the part that will be reduced to 3/4 of the original value)
Column D and E is for the section taken from column B and C respectively

New entry will be added by row.

```
A1 = 45    
B1 = 25    
C1 = A1 - B1 = 20    
D1 = 0.5    
E1 = 0.75    
F1 = if(A1>=B1, B1*D1+C1*E1, B1*D1)
```

So what do I have in the cell F1? If A1 is bigger than B1 (if 45 is bigger than 25), then find the sum of B1*D1 (25*0.5) and of C1*E1 (20*0.75), if not, then return the value of B1*D1 (25*0.5). With the specific values you give, the answer of 27.5 is found in F1 (after pressing enter)

Such a layout allow you to "play" with your data, changing the first number (in column A) as well as any other value in columns B to E.

Sample:
[image]

However, if you want to keep the three values unchanged: The first section (25), The two ratios (50% and 75%), then

Input A1 as 25, A2 as 0.5 and A3 as 0.75

Right the title you want in C1 and D1

```
C2 = 45

D2 =IF($C2<$A$1,$A$1*$A$2,$A$1*$A$2+($C2-$A$1)*$A$3)
```

Sample 2:

[image]

Comment: Thx @ComradeH, I will see which solution fit my needs best :).

Comment: @Materazzi23 I have also added the screenshot of the two solutions, please check the numbers I have on the screen to see if they meet your criteria. And please upvote my answer :)